# I can't install Spring STS in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

[image: Error dialog]

Details :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_asusm_eclipse_java-2022-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.hierynomus.sshj,0.24.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.jcraft.jzlib,1.1.3.v20220502-1820
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,io.projectreactor.reactor-core,3.3.1.202003091750-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang3,3.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.dadacoalition.yedit,1.0.18.201602092025-RELEASE-SIGNED
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.reactivestreams.reactive-streams,1.0.3
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.boot.ide.main.feature,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: binary,org.springframework.boot.ide.main.feature_root,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.live,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.cf,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.docker,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.feature,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.refactoring,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.restart,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.templates,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.validation,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.buildship30,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.docker.client,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.editor.support,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.imports,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.pom,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.feature,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls,1.39.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.feature,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.cloudfoundry.manifest.ls,1.39.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.jdt.ls.commons,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.gotosymbol,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.boot.ls,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.cloudfoundry.client.v2,4.16.0.202209151144
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.jdk_tools,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.livexp,4.16.0.202209151102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.ui,4.16.0.202209151102
```

Comment: So it can't find a lot of stuff. How are you doing the install? What repositories/ does Eclipse know about?

Answer (score 1):

You can download STS on this website https://spring.io/tools STS is also an eclipse software and it's used for Spring development.